# Past + and + past / Past perfect continuous + and + past

Tags: tense

> I met a girl at a park a month ago and I asked her for her number. (since that / after that ) we had been keeping in touch on the phone (with each other) for about 2 weeks (when we met in person / and then we met in person )

1. I think I can use both.
2. Using with each other here depends on preference.

3.

-I'm more familiar with "**we had been keeping in touch for about 2 weeks when we met in person"**

but I still think I can say **"we had been keeping in touch for about 2 weeks, and then we met in person"**,

but I would rather say like this instead :**"we kept in touch for about 2 weeks, and then we met in person"**

The reason I think this way is because we mix two past tense using ***"and"***(***past*** + and + ***past***), I feel **"we kept in touch for about 2 weeks, and then we met in person"** is more natural than using ***past perfect continuous*** + and + ***past***.

Am I right to think this way?

Comment: You only need to use past perfect if you refer to a point in time that is further back than the point you are currently explaining. In other words, if the three events you described (original meeting, contact on the phone, meet again in person) are being described in chronological order, there is no need for past perfect. Is this the case in your opinion?

Comment: I wouldn't say "we had been keeping in touch for about two weeks, and then we met in person" for the reasons you ably explain.

Comment: @BobRodes I think this is an adverbial clause. isn't it ? I love them ? they are really applicable ? specifically, in writing!